# Impala - Running Same Query Over Multiple Dates

Tags: sql, loops, date, impala

I have the below Impala query which is set to count the number of devices that are in the data set one day but not the day before. I would like to run this query over multiple dates (every day in the past year).

Is there any way to do this in Impala? I know there is no loop functionality, but wasn't sure if there was some way to pass an array of dates into a variable so that the query runs over consecutive dates. Thanks!

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT devices) 
FROM request
WHERE devices NOT IN (
    SELECT devices
    FROM request
    WHERE forwarded_dt =  CAST((CAST('2020-03-17' as timestamp)) as BIGINT)*1000
    )  
AND forwarded_dt =  CAST((CAST('2020-03-18' as timestamp)) as BIGINT)*1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()`.  I think:

```
select day,
       count(*) as num_devices_on_day,
       sum(case when prev_day = day - interval '1' day then 0 else 1 end) as new_devices_on_day
from (select device, date_trunc('day', timestamp) as day,
             lag(date_trunc('day', timestamp)) over (order by min(timestamp)) as prev_day
      from requests
     ) r
group by day;
```